# return value form promise IONIC 5

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am a IONIC newbie
I have following function that returns membership plan.

```
  async getMembership(){
       await this.Products.WooCommerceAPI().get('memberships/plans').then( (data) => {
       this.plans = data.data.map(e => ({

       // used spread method here to call another function that gets the price 
        ...e,
        price: this.getPlanPrice(e.access_product_ids[0]).then(async (res) => {
          return  await res;
        }),
      }));
    }).catch((error) => {
      // Invalid request, for 4xx and 5xx statuses
      console.log('Response Status:', error.response.status);
      console.log('Response Headers:', error.response.headers);
      console.log('Response Data:', error.response.data);
    })
    .finally(() => {
      // Always executed.
    });
    console.log(this.plans);
  }
```

in this function I used another function that gets price of each membership using `...` spread method.

```
    async getPlanPrice(id): Promise<any> {
    if (id !== undefined) {
      return await this.Products.WooCommerceAPI().get('products/' + id).then(data => {
        return data.data;
      });
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }
```

but the problem is

```
price: this.getPlanPrice(e.access_product_ids[0]).then(async (res) => {
          return  await res;
        }),
```

this part return `[Object Promise]` I have tried everything but can't get price for example `500` insdeat of this object promise.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the result of the promise before assigning it as an object property, even if you use then it stays as a Promise.
Something similar to this should work:

```
 await this.Products.WooCommerceAPI().get('memberships/plans').then( (data) => {
       this.plans = data.data.map(e => {
           const price = await this.getPlanPrice(e.access_product_ids[0]);
           return {...e, price}
       });
```

Comment: still a promise object

Comment: ` const price = this.getPlanPrice(e.access_product_ids[0]);
          console.log(price);
          return {...e, price};
        });`